# Key hashes for Facebook apps

Tags: android, facebook

The breathtakingly flippant Facebook docs say I have to run:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %HOMEPATH%\.android\debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

to create a debug key hash, whatever each of those things are.

I noticed that in my home dir I already have an `.android` folder and a file `debug.keystore` in it. If I follow Facebook's instructions, will I overwrite this `debug.keystore` file or anything in it and possibly mess up whatever it's used for? What if there's already an alias (whatever that is) called androiddebugkey? Do I have to name it androiddebugkey?

I'm sorry, I've made maybe 10 apps for Android but I don't know anything about cryptography.

Comment: Here is some documentation https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore.html

Comment: Yes, I've read that already and I didn't understand any of it. I just need a simple share button in my app, and now I find out I have to sit through a cryptography course. Yes, I'm stupid.

Comment: For getting facebook hashes out of keystores you can also try this code: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13488560/2015751 You can print the hash of the keystore you are using at the moment directly from the app. This way you don't have to care which debug keystore you use. (Just remember to repeat this for you production keystore once you publish your app. And certainly delete this code from the publicly available APK - you don't want other people to read that ;))